# How to have two deployments into production and none in staging?

Tags: azure, swap, production, staging

this is my situation: I have a BizSpark account which gives me 1500 hours per month of Azure instances for free. So, I can use only 2 instances to not be billed.

I have one deployment with one instance in Production and another deployment with an instance in Staging. I want to have my secondary deployment (ans its instance, of course) in Production also. But I only see the "Swap VIP" option to interchanged one by the other. I want the two Deployments go into production and only use the Staging mode for changes.

How can I do that? Or I'm missing something?

Note: I know that I can have a Deployment with 2 instances. But in that case, for updates, I should set an Staging Deployment (with also 2 instantces for later be swapped), but that would use 4 instances for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your production instance is the only instance addressible through a known URL (e.g. foo.cloudapp.net). Your staging instance(s) are addressible only through a (random) GUID prefix (e.g. 61C91C4B-D949-4C62-837C-F780586F96D8.cloudapp.net). Therefore your staging instance(s) should not be relied upon for production use.

If you want multiple instances of your service running, then configure your service to require two instances. Then, when it comes to deployment, deploy your new service to staging, test that it works as expected and then VIP-swap. Your new service will now be in production and your old site is in staging. Confirm that your new service is working as expected, and then delete your (now old) staging deployment.

Comment: I see, so... Azure forces us to duplicate our number of active instances for at least the time an update+swap happens.

Comment: Essentially, yes. The point of staging is to allow you to get your proposed runtime environment up into the cloud to ensure it works in the live environment. Some people go as far as deploying to staging, but pointing at test storage and SQL. Then, when they're happy their production tests work, they update config to point at live storage and SQL, restart staging and VIP-swap. The time differential required to certify a new update for production should be relatively quick and barely make a measurable difference to your monthly billing - it'll likely cost you pennies.